# MATLAB: plot in a loop

Tags: matlab

I've tried to do plot inside of a loop and it prints only the last plot.

How can i fix it?

I've tried to use `hold on` and `drawnow` after the plot definition but it didn't work.

This is my code:

```
for t=1:5
  alive = Game(World , Generations, speed);
  plot(hplot2,1:Generations,alive);
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hold on` should work. Try this:

```
figure
hplot2=gca;
hold on
for t=1:5
    alive = rand(1,Generations);
    plot(hplot2,1:Generations,alive);
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Sticking in a "figure" has always worked for me.

```
for t=1:5
    alive = Game(World , Generations, speed);
    figure;
    plot(hplot2,1:Generations,alive);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already passing the axes handle to `plot`, you only need to put something like `pause(0.1)` inside the loop, and your original source will work.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `figure(t)` to have 5 different figures.

Answer (score 0):

If the function `Game(World , Generations, speed)` is a deterministic function - it gives the same output for every `t`. Therefore, every `plot` commands has **exactly** the same output and you cannot distinguish the first from the last plot.

Try `plot` a random series at each iteration (as in answer of shoelzer) and see if you see all 5 plots.

Additionally, you might want to use `hold all` instead of `hold on`: this way each plot will get a different color from the colormap.